# SQL Server Job hanging after running powershell cmd

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple command I am running as a SQL Server Agent job using the PowerShell setting:

```
$Command = 'Copy-SqlLogin -Source [Instance1] -Destination [Instance2]'
Invoke-Expression $Command  > c:\@oneneck\loginpushresultsa.txt
exit(0)
```

The command is a DBATOOLS command with DBA tools installed on both boxes. Now, I know the command works fine because the loginpushresultsa.txt file gets filled every time.

The problem is that it is not exiting. It stays hung up on the job forever after that and I'm not sure how to get it to close and finish.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you run this in powershell instead of agent does it work? I'm a big fan of using windows task scheduler to invoke PS instead of using SQL Server